# ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift line 444 Fatal error: Index out of range:

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Overall code is working fine I am using `pulltorefreshControl` for `UITableView`. Whenever I refresh it through `pulltoRefresh` it gives me  `Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444`

error highlighted on `let dic = Appdata![indexPath.row]` in cellForRowAt function.

My code is simple one just fetching data from JSON response.

declared on top: `var Appdata : [Appointment]? = []`

JSON reponse code:

```
func appointmentCall(_ someDateTime:Date) {
        
        self.Appdata?.removeAll()        
        DataProvider.main.serviceGetAppointment(date: someDateTime, callback: {success, result in
            
            do{
                if(success){

                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
                    self.Appdata = response.appointments
    
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    
                    return true
                }else{
                    self.Appdata?.removeAll()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    return false
                }
            }catch let error {
                
                print(error as Any)
                return false
            }
        })
        
       
        
    }
```

pull to refresh function:

```
@objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        
    // refresh tableview datasource
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        sender.beginRefreshing()
        self.Appdata?.removeAll()
        self.appointmentCall(appointDate)
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
        
}
```

TableView code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Appdata?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AppointmentTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AppointmentTableViewCell        
    let dic = Appdata![indexPath.row]
    
    
    cell.rightView.backgroundColor = dic.backgroundColorLight?.toColor() ?? ("#cfd8dc").toColor()
    cell.rightView.layer.applySketchShadow()
    cell.topLabel.text = dic.projectName
    cell.midLabel.text = dic.subTitle
    cell.leftView.backgroundColor = dic.backgroundColorDark?.toColor() ?? ("#556f7b").toColor()
    cell.rightLabel.text = dic.projectDistrict
    cell.leftTopLabel.text = dic.appointmentHour
    cell.leftBotLabel.text = dic.controlHour
    cell.botLabel.text = dic.projectFirmName
    
    return cell
    
}
```

Comment: I think you have your main queue dispatch in the wrong place. I would be very surprised if the pull to refresh handler wasn't already on the main queue but the completion handler from your data provider probably isn't. It looks like you are suffering from non-thread safe update of your array.  Dispatch the code in the completion handler onto the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. I have set it accordingly, its working perfectly.